# how can i show two output in a same time in terminal with python?

Tags: python, printing, timer, multiprocessing, output

I need this output  in my program:

```
   from __future__ import print_function
   import time
   import threading

  def timer():
   for h in range(0, 24):
    for m in range(0, 60):
      for s in range(0, 60):
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("Elapsed time : %s:%s:%s" % (h, m, s), end="\r")

  def insert_record():
     #do insert record operation below code is sample     
        count = 0
        for i in range(1, 100):
           count += 1
           time.sleep(1)
           print ("Inserted records in mysql database : %s " % count, end="\r")

  if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=insert_record()).start()
    threading.Thread(target=timer()).start()
```

until insert_record function() is working, timer() function show elapsed time in next line.
but didn't show elapsed time in terminal :-( 
just showed insert_record() output in terminal.

i want this output :

Inserted records in mysql database : 5456672

Elapsed time :  20:15:30

please help me ,sorry about bad english dictate.

Comment: Do you want to run the program in a command line loop? Or are you talking about a loop in the program that should show the time every cycle? You have to clarify, otherwise it is difficult to help.

Comment: andi can you see my code again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start a thread by giving it the function, don't call the function immediately :)
2. The default output is buffered.  Use `sys.stderr`, or the `logging` module.

   from **future** import print_function
   import sys, time
   import threading

   def timer():
       for h in range(0, 24):
           for m in range(0, 60):
               for s in range(0, 60):
                   time.sleep(1)
                   sys.stderr.write(
                       "Elapsed time : %s:%s:%s\n" % (h, m, s)
                       )

   def insert_record():
       #do insert record operation below code is sample
       count = 0
       for i in range(1, 100):
           count += 1
           time.sleep(1)
           sys.stderr.write(
               "Inserted records in mysql database : %s\n" % count
               )

   if **name** == "**main**":
       print('start')
       threading.Thread(target=insert_record).start()
       threading.Thread(target=timer).start()

   ```
   print('join')
   for t in threading.enumerate():
       if t != threading.current_thread():
           t.join()
   ```